# Change in the model doesn't affect the DOM Checkbox AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, checkbox

I am using a checkbox binded to a `$scope` variable in AngularJS. My code is something like:

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.selected">` and I have an object in my controller `$scope.value` which has the `selected` property. The changes in the DOM i.e. clicking the checkbox changes the values of the `selected` property in the `value` object but the vice versa, i.e. if I change the `selected` property in the controller it doesn't change the DOM checkbox. Any suggestions or workarounds would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Button select selects checkbox and button deselect - deselects it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Ajax with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The form</h2>

<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.selected"/>
<p>{{value.selected}}</p>

<button ng-click="select()">Select</button>
<button ng-click="deselect()">Deselect</button>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('mainController',function($scope){
  $scope.value = {
       selected:false
     };
  $scope.select = function(){
    $scope.value.selected = true;
  }
  $scope.deselect = function() {
    $scope.value.selected = false;
  }
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this method too. When I tried your code in Plunker it worked, but when I try to replicate it in my code it doesnt change anything in the DOM but the model still has its value changed.